# How can I access string value in an array?

Tags: php, array, oop, user-access, terms

currently I am developing a site using the Dokan multivendor plugin. I added a custom field in the registration form and

The below code is being used to add the custom field in the registration form

```
<p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
    <label for="tskypeid"><?php _e( 'Skype ID', 'dokan-lite' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="tskypeid" id="tskype-id" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $postdata['tskypeid'] ) ) echo esc_attr($postdata['tskypeid']); ?>" required="required" />
</p>
```

This is code that is being used to save the field data:

```
// save skype id after registration

function ms_dokan_on_create_seller( $user_id, $data ) {
    if ( $data['role'] != 'seller' ) {
        return;
    }

    $dokan_settings = array(
        'tskypeid'          => $_POST['tskypeid'],
    );

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_profile_settings', $dokan_settings );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_store_name', $dokan_settings['store_name'] );

    do_action( 'dokan_new_seller_created', $user_id, $dokan_settings );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'ms_dokan_on_create_seller', 10, 2);
```

tried to access the value using the below code:

```
function wc_vendors_name_loop( $store_id ) {
    $user_id    = get_current_user_id();
    $dokan_profile_settings = get_user_meta( $user_id ) 
    ['dokan_profile_settings'];
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $dokan_profile_settings );
    echo "</pre>";
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_vendors_name_loop' );
```

This code outputs the below result:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1183) 
    "a:17:{
        s:8:"tskypeid";
        s:7:"asdfasd";
        s:10:"store_name";
        s:17:"asdfas dfasdfasdf";
        s:9:"store_ppp";
        i:0;s:7:"address";
        a:6:{
            s:8:"street_1";
            s:19:"fasdf asdf asdf sad";
            s:8:"street_2";
            s:15:"sadf asdf asd f";
            s:4:"city";
            s:10:"asdf asd f";
            s:3:"zip";
            s:8:"sad fsad";
            s:7:"country";
            s:2:"AZ";
            s:5:"state";
            s:9:"asdfasdf ";
        }
        s:8:
        "location";
        s:0:"";
        s:12:"find_address";
        s:27:"dsfas sadf sadfsadfsadf asf";
        s:6:"banner";
        i:0;s:5:"phone";
        s:9:"345346456";
        s:10:"show_email";
        s:3:"yes";
        s:14:"show_more_ptab";
        s:3:"yes";
        s:8:"gravatar";
        i:0;s:10:"enable_tnc";
        s:2:"on";
        s:9:"store_tnc";
        s:27:"asdf asdf asdfa sdf sadfsdf";
        s:18:"profile_completion";
        a:6:{
            s:5:"phone";
            i:10;s:10:"store_name";
            i:10;s:7:"address";
            i:10;s:9:"next_todo";
            s:31:"Add Banner to gain 15% progress";
            s:8:"progress";
            i:30;s:13:"progress_vals";
            a:8:{
                s:10:"banner_val";
                i:15;s:19:"profile_picture_val";
                i:15;s:14:"store_name_val";
                i:10;s:10:"social_val";
                a:5:{
                    s:2:"fb";
                    i:2;s:5:"gplus";
                    i:2;s:7:"twitter";
                    i:2;s:7:"youtube";
                    i:2;s:8:"linkedin";
                    i:2;
                }
                s:18:"payment_method_val";
                i:15;s:9:"phone_val";
                i:10;s:11:"address_val";
                i:10;s:7:"map_val";
                i:15;
            }
        }
        s:23:"show_min_order_discount";
        s:2:"no";
        s:28:"setting_minimum_order_amount";
        s:0:"";
        s:24:"setting_order_percentage";
        s:0:"";
    }"
}
```

Here I want to access the value of "tskypeid" in line 5 and the value is "asdfasd" in line 6

Please tell me how can I access that value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to get those meta keys via WordPress, you can use the `get_user_meta()` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

`get_user_meta( $user_id, 'tskypeid', true )`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried using get_user_meta( $user_id, 'tskypeid', true ) but it returns string(0) "" butit should return "asdfasd". Can you help me out fixing this???

Comment: How is this data being saved - can you add that code to the question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it. Waiting for your reply. Thank you.

Comment: The actual key is `dokan_profile_settings` and `tskypeid` is an element of that array. So you'd need to `$data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'tskypeid', true )` then `echo $data['tskypeid']`.

Comment: I edited the code with your instruction like this and it's returning illegal string offset error. Please let me know my mistake. Thank you for your efforts of helping me find out the issue.                            function wc_vendors_name_loop( $store_id ) {
 $user_id    = get_current_user_id();
 $dokan_profile_settings = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'tskypeid', true );
 echo "<pre>";
 echo $dokan_profile_settings['tskypeid'];
 echo "</pre>";
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_vendors_name_loop' );

Comment: This is the error it's throwing: Warning: Illegal string offset 'tskypeid' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\wordpress\taqoh\wp-content\themes\rehub-vendor\functions.php on line 106

Comment: This is not returning the normal key as tskypeid. Please have a look at the last array in my question. This is what it's returning after I var_dump. Thank you. @JacobPeattie

Comment: There's something wrong with the way you're saving the data. That array has a lot more data in it than just `tskypeid`, but your saving code only includes that key. Please include the full and actual save function.

Comment: Woohoo! I got it fixed with this code.    
function wc_vendors_name_loop() {
 $store_id = dokan_get_current_user_id();
 $existing_dokan_settings = get_user_meta( $store_id, 'dokan_profile_settings', true );
 echo $existing_dokan_settings['tskypeid'];
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_vendors_name_loop' );      Now I can display the skype id in the front end. Thank you so much for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! I got it fixed with this code. function

```
wc_vendors_name_loop() { 
    $store_id = dokan_get_current_user_id(); 
    $existing_dokan_settings = get_user_meta( $store_id, 'dokan_profile_settings', true ); 
    echo $existing_dokan_settings['tskypeid']; 
} 
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_vendors_name_loop' );
```

Now I can display the skype id in the front end.